# Upper bound for $\sum_{j=0}^i {i \choose j}^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Is there an upper bound for sums of powers of binomial coefficients?  I have  $$\sum_{j=0}^i {i \choose j}^{n}$$

where $n$ is a positive integer.

I am hoping this will help me solve [Limit of $\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{{n \choose i}}{2^{in}}\sum_{j=0}^i {i \choose j}^{n+1}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608296/limit-for-a-double-sum-of-binomials) .

Comment: Crude upper bound: each term is bounded above by $i^n$, so their sum is bounded by $i^{n+1}$.

Comment: How tight a bound do you want? You can get a full asymptotic expansion using Laplace's method...

Comment: @IgorRivin My aim is to prove the limit http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608296/limit-of-sum-i-1n-left-fracn-choose-i2in-sum-j-0i-i-choose using this bound but I don't know exactly how tight it has to be for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient). $$\sum<(i+1)\bigg[2^i\sqrt\frac2{i\pi}\bigg(1-\frac1{4i}\bigg)\bigg]^n$$

Comment: You mean bound it by $(i+1)2^{in}/i^{n/2}$?

Comment: I think there's a small typo in your formula, and I also think you should use the last one, which provides the best accuracy, but yeah, that's pretty much the idea.

Comment: Thank you. Numerically it seems this is tight enough for my limit problem.  I still don't know how to prove it however.

Comment: Should that be $1/8i$ instead of $1/4i$ ?

Comment: $i=2n\iff4i=8n$

Comment: Ah yes.. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $x,y \geq 0$, then $x^n + y^n \leq (x + y)^n$ for any $n \geq 1$.

By induction, we can show $\sum_{j = 0}^{i} C(i,j)^n \leq \Big(\sum_{j = 0}^{i} C(i,j)\Big)^n = (2^i - 1)^n$.

The bound is a tad crude, though.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I think that is too loose  to prove the limit I need.